# Is there a Blog Website that is not using a Content Manaegement System?

Tags: content-management-system

I just want to ask if there are still blog sites that are manually, or not using any content management system? Could you please give me an example (if there are any)? Thanks.

Comment: I think the name says it all...

Comment: This *cough* *cough* strategy *cough* is heavily used by my instructors, where each entry is delimited by a `<hr />`. But course progress isn't a blog...

Comment: i just want an example site, if there is.

Comment: 8 questions, 2 chosen answers, and 0 votes... good luck getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well... if you just want it as an example site and not as an actual blogging system, then I would suggest finding a blog site that you like that uses php as all the entries will be seemingly be hard coded into the html. Copy the html and the css then take out the branding with just html/css editing so that you have the general layout. Make sure you get permission though (a friend + freeware?).

Else the best you can get are flat file blogs that don't save to databases.

Self editing html systems would be tricky... unless you made it a php site and used sessions so that people could test it out without it actually saving. Sorry that's the best I can think of on this matter.

As jondavidjohn said, it's a bit of a contradiction.

I hope these help,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

It's becoming quite fashionable to run flat HTML pages these days. Take a look at scripts like http://nanoc.stoneship.org/ which allow you to author blogs and generate static HTML for you.